# Selecting and Pasting Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm relatively new to VBA, I have only some experience with Python and only very little experience looking at other VBA macros and adjusting them to my need, so I'm trying to do what I can.

What I am trying to do is for each part number pasted in worksheet B (worksheet B, row A) I want to find the same part number from a different worksheet containing all part numbers (worksheet D, row A) and copy the description (worksheet D, row H) from worksheet D to another column, (worksheet B, row D) then check the next part number in the row and repeat.

The current error that I'm getting is that there is "Compile error: Else without if", I'm sorry that I am not very proficient, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Other information:

-My part numbers to search through in worksheet B, column B are filled in from worksheet A, is it okay to just make it =A!B2 or =CONCATENATE(A!B2)?

```
Sub Description()

Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet, wsC As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Set wsB = Worksheets("B")
Set wsD = Worksheets("D")

Do: aRow = 2
        If wsB.Cells(aRow, 2) <> "" Then
     With Worksheets("D").Range("A:A")
        x = wsB.Cells(aRow, 2)
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=x, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)

        Selection.Copy
        wsB.Cells(dRow, 2).Paste
     dRow = dRow + 1
    Else
        aRow = aRow + 1

Loop Until wsB.Cells(aRow, 2) = ""
End Sub
```

Thanks again!

Edit: Can't Execute code in break mode is current error

```
Sub Description()
Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet, wsC As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Set wsB = Worksheets("B")
Set wsD = Worksheets("D")
aRow = 2
dRow = 2

    Do:
        If wsB.Cells(aRow, 1) <> "" Then
            With Worksheets("D").Range("A:A")
                Set Rng = .Find(What:=wsB.Cells(aRow, 1), _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
                Rng.Copy
                Rng.Offset(0, 3).Paste (Cells(aRow, 4))
                dRow = dRow + 1
                aRow = aRow + 1
            End With
        End If
    Loop Until wsB.Cells(aRow, 1) = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put `End If` on the next line after `aRow = aRow + 1`. See MSDN for syntax msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

Comment: I believe an `End With` directly before the `Else` would be necessary as well. Actually better to move the `With ... End With` block outside of the `For ... Next` loop as it is not redefined by anything within the for ... next.

Comment: Yes. In VBA multiline statements require `End ***`

Comment: I put the aRow and dRow definitions above the Do: so it doesn't  reset it every time it loops

Answer (score 0):

In Excel we usually call vertical range as column, and horizontal one as row.
From your code and question description, I assume what you said "row A" is column A.
Also, your code scan through wsB.Cells(aRow, 2).  It is column B not column A.
Anyway, this is just a minor problem.

The following code will check cells of column B of worksheet B.  If the same value is found
in column A of worksheet D, then the cooresponding cell in column H of worksheet D will 
be copied to the cell in column B of worksheet B.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Description()
   Dim wsB As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet, aRow As Long
   Dim rngSearchRange As Range, rngFound As Range
   Set wsB = Worksheets("B")
   Set wsD = Worksheets("D")
   Set rngSearchRange = wsD.Range("A:A")
   aRow = 2
   Do While wsB.Cells(aRow, 2).Value <> ""
      Set rngFound = rngSearchRange.Find(What:=wsB.Cells(aRow, 2).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
      If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
         wsD.Cells(rngFound.Row, 8).Copy Destination:=wsB.Cells(aRow, 4)  ' Indexes of Column H, D are respectively 8, 4
      End If
      aRow = aRow + 1
   Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very close for me, one problem is that it's not finding the items, but only pasting them in order, so if I have 12 items its pasting the first 12 from worksheet D.

Comment: Is it somehow checking on worksheet B instead of D, so that it matches every time and is pasting from worksheet D?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me.

```
Sub Description()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheets("B").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim foundRng As Range
    For Each rng In Sheets("B").Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
        Set foundRng = Sheets("D").Range("A:A").Find(rng, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not foundRng Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("B").Cells(rng.Row, "D") = Sheets("D").Cells(foundRng.Row, "H")
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```